# TypeError: todo is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, postman

I am trying to do a post request from the postman with the following url localhost:3000/todos .However ,on making this request the status reads 500 internal server error .I am also getting an error in the body where it says todo is not a function.
Here is server.js

```
var express=require('express');
var bodyParser=require('body-parser');

var mongoose=require('./db/mongoose');
var Todo=require('./models/todo');
var User=require('./models/user');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/todos', (req, res) => {
  var todo = new Todo({
    text: req.body.text
  });

  todo.save().then((doc) => {
    res.send(doc);
  }, (e) => {
    res.status(400).send(e);
  });
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Started on port 3000');
});
```

And here is todo.js

```
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
var Todo = mongoose.model('Todo', {
  text: {
    type: String,
    required:true,
    minlength:1,
    trim:true

  },
  completed: {
    type: Boolean,
    default:false
  },
  completedAt: {
    type: Number,
    default:null
  }
});
module.exports={Todo};
```

Comment: For this to work you have two alternatives: `module.exports=Todo;`

The other is to make the following change `var Todo=require('./models/todo').Todo;` because you exported Todo as key value of an object while you exported

Comment: `module.exports=Todo;`

Comment: Hey Can you specify the chnage as what and where do I need to change.

Comment: @Alex it works fine.

Answer (score 4):

you're exporting an Object that contains your Todo Object so you either access that with :

`var todo = new Todo.Todo({ ...`  (in `server.js`)

or, in `Todos.js` :

`module.exports=Todo;` instead of `module.exports={Todo};` and you leave `server.js` as is.